# COUNT of different tables in GROUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that holds a list of classes available at a school. Each class can have a number of sessions. And each class can have pupils assigned to it.

What I need to do is get a count of all sessions for each class, as well as the number of students attending the class. I have done the first bit, but if I join to the pupil allocation table, my counts will be wrong.

I have conjured up some fake SQL that you can use.

I'm stuck with efficiently getting a count from the Pupil link table.

```
DECLARE @Class TABLE
(
    ClassID INT NOT NULL,
    ClassName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Class VALUES (1, 'English')
INSERT INTO @Class VALUES (2, 'Maths')

DECLARE @ClassSession TABLE
(
    ClassSessionID INT NOT NULL,
    ClassID INT NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @ClassSession VALUES (1, 1, 'Basic English')
INSERT INTO @ClassSession VALUES (2, 1, 'Advanced English')
INSERT INTO @ClassSession VALUES (3, 1, 'Amazing English')
INSERT INTO @ClassSession VALUES (4, 2, 'Basic English')
INSERT INTO @ClassSession VALUES (5, 2, 'Basic English')

DECLARE @ClassPupil TABLE
(
    ClassPupilID INT NOT NULL,
    ClassID INT NOT NULL,
    PupilID INT NOT NULL -- FK to the Pupils table.
)

INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (1, 1, 1000) 
INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (2, 1, 1001) 
INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (3, 1, 1002) 
INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (4, 1, 1003) 
INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (5, 1, 1004) 

INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (6, 2, 1005) 
INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (7, 2, 1006) 
INSERT INTO @ClassPupil VALUES (8, 2, 1007) 


SELECT ClassName, COUNT(*) AS Sessions, '??' AS NumerOfPupils
FROM @Class c
INNER JOIN @ClassSession cs
ON cs.ClassID = c.ClassID
GROUP BY c.ClassID, c.ClassName
```

It can maybe be done with a sub query? Is that the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two independent dimensions for each class.  You need to aggregat them separately:

```
SELECT c.ClassName, cs.Sessions, cp.Pupils
FROM @Class c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ClassId, COUNT(*) as sessions
      FROM @ClassSession cs 
      GROUP BY ClassId
     ) cs
     ON cs.ClassID = c.ClassID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ClassId, COUNT(*) as pupils
      FROM @ClassPupil cp
      GROUP BY ClassId
     ) cp
     ON cp.ClassId = c.ClassId;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use `CROSS APPLY` to get the count of pupils:

```
SELECT 
    ClassName, COUNT(*) AS Sessions, cp.NumberOfPupils
FROM @Class c
INNER JOIN @ClassSession cs
    ON cs.ClassID = c.ClassID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPupils
    FROM @ClassPupil
    WHERE
        ClassID = c.ClassID
) cp
GROUP BY c.ClassID, c.ClassName, cp.NumberOfPupils
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClassName, COUNT(distinct cs.ClassSessionID) AS Sessions, /*'??'*/ count( distinct cp.PupilID) AS NumerOfPupils
FROM @Class c
INNER JOIN @ClassSession cs
ON cs.ClassID = c.ClassID
inner join @ClassPupil cp on c.ClassID=cp.ClassID
GROUP BY /*c.ClassID,*/ c.ClassName
```

count(distinct...) solves (works around) the problem.
Generally, this is (A -> B, C) issue.